# Reviewing question, can we toggle the review button?

Tags: feature-request, review

As I see the review functionality in SO:

- we can review questions to rate or improve the content, but I see one small thing missing: can we include a feature where we can toggle the review option, i.e when you click review button, it will show the question to review, and there is no way to minimize or hide that review if we are reviewing many posts.
- as of now it will expand each question, which takes too much space. It's hard to scroll, for reviewing questions. So I thought it would be nice if there was a toggle button to show/hide the questions.

[image: toggeling review to hide or show]

Comment: -1 It can't be a *real* feature-request if it doesn't have red-freehand-circles.

Comment: for that u made a downvote ?? its needed functionality  :-/

Comment: I think Bobby was joking. There's a thread called [The Many Memes of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/154674) that he's referencing in that joke.

Comment: :) okies, will use circles now onward :)

Comment: +1, I really like this idea.

Comment: but it seems no one are telling their opinions about the feature :-/

Comment: is here any one to think about this feature ? moderators neded attention

Comment: I totally endorse this proposal!

Comment: +1, Very much needed. Is there a proposal to include this feature in the near future?

Comment: is there any status update for above feature request >

Comment: is there any status update for above request ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like this idea.  Why not add the same collapse button that the 10K tools have?

[image]

You could have everything collapsed by default (as it currently is), and instead of, or in addition to the review link, users could click the expand triangle to review the question, which would update the user's stats just like the review button currently does.  Except now users would also be able to collapse questions if they so choose.

Comment: is there any status update for above request ? waiting for this.